# How do I group 2 columns with a max value in a third column using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group

With this table....

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id INT,
  date VARCHAR(50),
  g1 VARCHAR(50),
  stats INT
 );
 
 INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,'2002-01-01','a',2);
 INSERT INTO test VALUES (2,'2002-01-02','a',3);
 INSERT INTO test VALUES (3,'2002-01-03','a',4);
 INSERT INTO test VALUES (4,'2002-01-01','b',9);
 INSERT INTO test VALUES (5,'2002-01-02','b',8);
 INSERT INTO test VALUES (6,'2002-01-03','b',7);
 INSERT INTO test VALUES (7,'2002-01-01','c',6);
 INSERT INTO test VALUES (8,'2002-01-02','c',9);
 INSERT INTO test VALUES (9,'2002-01-03','c',5);
```

I would like to get the following result.

| date | g1 | MAX(stats) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2002-01-03 | a | 4 |
| 2002-01-01 | b | 9 |
| 2002-01-02 | c | 9 |

I have this query. But adding the date column has been challenging.

```
SELECT g1, MAX(stats)
FROM test
GROUP BY g1
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mysql version suuport `ROW_NUMBER` window function you can try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY g1 ORDER BY stats DESC) rn
 FROM test
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

or `EXISTS` subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM test t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM test tt
    WHERE tt.g1 = t1.g1
    HAVING MAX(tt.stats) = t1.stats
)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e461920d6aa65762048ca361103ece9)

Answer (score 1):

An extra join should work, I have used the CTE style here but you can use a subquery too.

```
WITH temp as (SELECT g1, MAX(stats) as stats
FROM test
GROUP BY g1)
SELECT test.date, temp.g1, temp.stats FROM test INNER JOIN temp ON temp.stats = test.stats AND temp.g1 = test.g1;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cvq37zrwEtdHNnQTbJydHK/0